# Can Local Storage retain values even after app kill in Hybrid Ionic Cordova Mobile App (AngularJS based project)?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, local-storage

I have a Ionic Cordova Hybrid mobile app. It is AngularJS v1 Project. Can local storage be used to store data? Will the stored data be available after app kill?

Comment: https://ionicframework.com/docs/storage/

Comment: From my knowledge they will stay even if you reopen the app, but if you really want to keep them alive, why don't you use SQLite?

Comment: @Dehli I am using Ionic v1 and AngularJS v1. Can you please elaborate? The link you shared is for Ionic v3.

Comment: Problem with local storage is that it can be wiped by system on iOS device. This happens especially when device is low on storage.  You need to use plugin to get access to native storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The localstorage data for a ionic app is remains there after killing the app and the data will only be cleared when you clear the application data (for android) from settings->application->Your application -> storage -> clear data (not clear catch) or reinstalling the app

> localStorage.setItem('foo', 'bar');
>
> localStorage.getItem('foo');

alternatively you can use ionic native storage

ref https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/native-storage/

or cordova-sqlite-storage

ref https://ionicframework.com/docs/storage/

Comment: What is the difference between clear data and clear cache? Is local storage equal in persistence compared to SQLite?

Comment: clear data -> clear you application data
clear cache -> clear you application cache

Comment: SQLite is db structured and localstorage is key and value structured

Comment: There are 3 scenarios - 1. app kill ,  2. clear cache  , 3. clear data. Will there be same persistence for SQLite and HTML local storage for Hybrid Cordova apps?

Answer (score 1):

Use Ionic Native-Storage for devices and local-storage for browsers.

Comment: I am using Ionic v1 and AngularJS v1. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: you can use ionic Native-Storage in Ionic v1 since It is a Cordova plugin. use this to install the dependency  `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-nativestorage` . You can use it like `NativeStorage.setItem("reference", obj, setSuccess, setError);`